# Heroku crashes when fetching Image

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm running my NodeJS Server on heroku.

My website fetches lots of images 100 every connection from the nodejs server running on heroku.

Sometimes a image is getting fetched (look at error code below) and the server crashes.

Since a few days the heroku server crashes (10k) a day. I have never had this problem and haven't made any changes, also there is no big traffic increase.

The memory usage is low, 128mb out of 512mb also the Dyno load is also low.

The images are stored on the heroku server.

The errors are found below.

```
2021-05-02T18:56:44.339537+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/images/icons/thumb/raw/cosmos.png" host=www.X.com request_id=0ee560ac-3308-415f-bb4a-03a387523220 fwd="46.97.168.10,141.101.76.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http   

2021-05-02T18:56:44.343251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/images/icons/thumb/raw/avalanche-2.png" host=www.X.com request_id=199d8bdb-8018-43e7-9a29-396fd3b51779 fwd="46.97.168.10,172.69.55.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

2021-05-02T18:56:46.733391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/images/icons/thumb/raw/siacoin.png" host=www.X.com request_id=9a721235-c00f-439f-87a0-a8508cb81f40 fwd="46.97.168.10,172.69.55.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Are there any suggestions to fix this,  maybe a try and catch when fetching a images?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is showing H10 error which is due to app crash or boot timeout. This might be due to your app showing error during fetching of images. try using try catch for images.